# Docker-How do I connect to mysql container using a karaf container?

Tags: mysql, docker, apache-karaf

Im having some trouble filling my DB when installing a kar on karaf (Im using liquibase).
Im using windows 10, but using linux containers in docker, karaf 4.2.1 and mysql 5.7

There are the steps I did:

1-Went to task manager and stoped the mysql service.

2-Created and run a mysql 5.7 container doing the following:

```
docker run --name mysql-container -p 3306:3306 -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root -d mysql:5.7
```

Connected using 127.0.0.1 root/root in heidiSql and created the required DB's so when installing the kar liquibase will fill them with data.

3-Copied the kar to the repo folder in my karaf folder, added the folder to .tar, and then to gzip (.tar.gzip)

4-Created my karaf container using:

```
.\build.sh --from-local-dist --archive apache-karaf-with-kar.tar.gz
```

5-Did run karaf in the background:

```
docker run -d -p 127.0.0.1:8101:8101 --name=karaf-container karaf
```

Now I used putty and ssh to connect to karaf - localhost:8101. enter the user karaf and pass karaf.
All ok, I do the kar:install command, kar install but the bundles are in grace period.
I go to heidiSql and see that the DB's are not filled with data.

I go back to karaf connection, do a feature:refresh and i get erros like:

```
 Error resolving artifact org.ops4j.pax.transx:pax-transx-features:xml:features:0.3.0: [Could not transfer artifact org.ops4j.pax.transx:pax-transx-features:xml:features:0.3.0 from/to central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/): Failed to transfer file: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/ops4j/pax/transx/pax-transx-features/0.3.0/pax-transx-features-0.3.0-features.xml. Return code is: 501 , ReasonPhrase:HTTPS Required.]
```

I suposse the problem here is that somehow my connection to mysql doesn't work.
After some time the ssh connection is lost (I suposse this is normal if I dont do anything for some time there).

I tried to create a mysql-server container instead, but that way im not even able to connect using heidiSql.

Adicional question:
1-Where do I find the link to the kubernetes dashboard? I cant find it on docker.
2-I was having a first error when trying to docker run karaf:

```
\"karaf\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown.
```

I resolved that because I realised that my karaf folder had less files than a downloaded binary one.
Basically the files are the files you see when you open the folder, the build.md, license, etc...
So I did copy paste to my folder of those files and I was able to run it. Im asking, because its still a mystery to me...

Thanks for your attention

edit: tried stoping the mysql-container and started mysql from the task manager and its the same, now im sure that for some reason its not connecting to the DB's. so I guess the problem is when I create a karaf container, maybe im missing some configurations. gonna keep trying

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After 2 days I finally found the problem.

First, let me say that I did try too to create a network

```
docker network create mynet
```

and used the tag `docker run --network=mynet` in both mysql-container and karaf-container.
In my hook, I did try to replace localhost with mysql-container:3306 and even after that it didn't work.

Anyway, to resolve, I did what I said above, plus create a new super user:

```
docker exec -it mysql-container mysql -u root -p

CREATE USER 'user'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'pass';

GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'user'@'%';

FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

And after that, all worked fine.

I will leave here a usefull link that was kinda hard to find but it has pretty good info:
https://codebeamer.com/cb/wiki/5854748

plus, for the 2 extra questions I asked:
1- Still didnt find the kube dashboard, didn't look much for it yet to be honest.
2- For what I have seen in the build.sh it will search a specific folder name 'apache-karaf', so I think this error here happens if you rename your folder and it doesnt match with the build.sh.